# Can I add quarto snippets in the RStudio IDE?

Tags: rstudio, quarto

I would like to add these Quarto code snippets to the RStudio IDE:

```
# quarto callout note
snippet con
    :::{.callout-note appearance=minimal}
    ${1:text}
    :::

# quarto callout warning
snippet cow
    :::{.callout-warning appearance=simple}
    ${1:text}
    :::
```

The editor will only expand the snippets if the text is inside a code chunk.  Is there a fix/work-around to allow snippets in plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These snippets are expanding only inside the r-code chunk for your case, probably because you have defined these snippets in the R snippet. Instead, You need to add these snippets for Markdown to get these work.

So go to `Tools > Global Options > Code > Editing > Edit Snippets`, and then go to the section `Markdown` and paste these snippets there. Save, OK, apply.

Now after writing `con` in `qmd` file and then press `shift + Tab`.

---

Also be careful about pasting the snippet, so that any extra space doesn't get pasted with these. (While I tried to paste these snippets, these didn't work at first, because of extra spaces were pasted before `:::`)

Comment: Also as an alternative to snippet, you may wanna check out this package [`{quartostamp}`](https://matt-dray.github.io/quartostamp/index.html), which provides addins to insert pre-written divs and classes into the Quarto documents.